# Librosa installation pip fail

Tags: python, installation, error-handling, pip, librosa

I am trying to install librosa by pip install librosa on the mac terminal, pip3 also has the same problem. It also gets stuck when I try to install scikit-learn.

Doesn't go any further than:

```
Collecting librosa
  Using cached librosa-0.8.1-py3-none-any.whl (203 kB)
Collecting packaging>=20.0
  Using cached packaging-21.0-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.0 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from librosa) (1.21.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.0.0 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from librosa) (1.7.0)
Collecting numba>=0.43.0
  Using cached numba-0.53.1.tar.gz (2.2 MB)
Collecting resampy>=0.2.2
  Using cached resampy-0.2.2.tar.gz (323 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: soundfile>=0.10.2 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from librosa) (0.10.3.post1)
Collecting scikit-learn!=0.19.0,>=0.14.0
  Using cached scikit-learn-0.24.2.tar.gz (7.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... \
```

I am very new at this, please help I just want to draw some spectrograms.

python --version
Python 2.7.16

python3 --version
Python 3.9.6

pip --version
pip 21.1.3 from /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful for you to work in a virtual environment. If you are trying to install with python 3.9 there may be a number of dependency issues, so using a lower version may also solve your issues. However, do try to with a conda environment as this will allow you to more easily keep track of install packages etc. Here are the [install instructions](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/macos.html):

After the install you can create a conda environment with a lower python version:

```
conda create -n "py38" python=3.8 ipython
```

Activate the environment:

```
conda activate py38
```

Install librosa:

```
conda install -c conda-forge librosa
```

Comment: This is definetely a good tip. Although it doesn't answer the OP's question. Please check this link on [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)